# Does sharing the same IP necessarily mean sharing the same server?

Tags: web, hosting

I was curious as to why one client site on a shared server was performing very poorly and I wanted to know if there was a way to find out how many other sites were being hosted on the same server.  I found this reverse IP lookup site:

http://reverseip.domaintools.com/

that claims the client's site IP is also being used by 3000+ other sites.  I did a quick survey of other clients' sites and this is more than twice the next closest, most being in the 800 - 1500 range.

Does this mean that there are 3000+ sites being hosted on one server, or could there still be multiple servers sharing an IP?  Basically I want to know if this is the main likely reason the site is slow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On public internet, sharing the same IP address **does not** mean sharing the same physical server. Here are the ways of sharing an IP, and yet processing on different physical server:

1. Most often, the public IP addresses are the interfaced by a Load Balancer, or a Reverse Proxy, or a Gateway. This device then routes (technically proxies) the connection to one of the physical servers running behind them. All these are within the firewall/network/data_cente of the "serving" organization.
   Unless designed (or ill-designed) to reveal information about the internal IP addresses, there is no way to figure out the IP address of physical device that actually processed the request.
2. [Anycast](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anycast) allows you to have the same IP address being available at different geographical locations. Look at [Google's DNS servers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Public_DNS) (IP address 8.8.8.8). Such services are anycasted, to serve from the nearest geo-location.

This is also true from server's perspective. A server **does not** necessarily know the "original" IP address from where the request initiated. Most often, we are proxied, and/or [NAT'ed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation) by routers and other devices at our home and offices. After all, there are only so many public IP addresses available (at least IPv4), and we cannot have one public IP address for each device :) .

*Closing statement*: The server and the client only know the ingress/egress points of each other's network. Beyond that, they have no idea of the internal IP addresses of the physical devices.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it can very well mean that. It is very common, and is the only way companies selling you hosting for pennies can even approach turning a profit.

It is done with virtual hosting support in the web server. This relies on DNS and the browser / client providing the referrer URL to the server as part of the HTTP request. The HTTP server then knows who the client thinks he is requesting a URI from, and maps the request to that site tree. Those trees often sit on the same disk, though the sites may be jailed or virtualized.

I've seen numbers higher than 3000, for example.

If you want better, you have to move to a higher quality provider, and/or obtain your own IP addresses.

Comment: While it means that they *could* be proxied by the same host, they need not be *served* by the same host.

Comment: Technically true, but rare in my experience. The end result is the same for people concerned about sharing an IP address with potential spammers, hackers or botnets risking blacklisting.

Comment: Yes, if the concern is with sharing of IP address, then you *do* share the IP address, and will get affected. 
However, if the concern is *slowness* or *performance*, then sharing of IP address is a non-issue. Given that the processing happens on *different hosts*, the IP address **must not** be taken for being on same hardware. Its rather rare for services to be running on the front-end public IP.

Comment: @ManishMaheshwari - Honest question here (I'm traditionally used to Apache, Cisco PIX/ASA and Local Director). I suppose you have a point about different servers. I'd just never seen bulk virtual hosting done in combination with multiple physical servers. Are you saying it is common to do virtual REFERRER_URL virtual hosting with an edge device like a load balancer that is smart enough to direct to private IPs based, or are the disks/site content replicated across the physical servers so that the load balancer doesnt have to be aware of the virtual hosts?

Comment: I am referring to a load balancer (usually software), that performs basic security checks on the HTTP request, and then proxies to another host on private network (and private IP), where the site is deployed. The load balancers are smart, and fast, and can also monitor the backend sites for health, actively, or passively.

Comment: OK, I understood you correctly, and my original point was, when we do virtual hosting, we map many sites to the same public IP address, and in order to do that, the server(s) has to have all of the sites shared on disk. If a load balancer is used, then either all private nodes have to have all of the same sites (content), or the load balancer has to do more than just proxy to another host, it has to be aware of REFERRER_URL -> physical private IP mapping in order to proxy to the correct private IP(s).